# How to use activity to request data from service?

Tags: java, android

Now, my program have an activity and a service. The service runs in the background and sometimes vibrates to ask users give some selection. I meet a problem here. I know broadcast could pass data from service to activity. But if the activity is not working, then it cannot receive the broadcast information, so if user feels vibration but after a period of time start the activity then the activity will miss the broadcast information and cannot ask user to choose a selection. So does anybody know how to actively request the data from the service by activity? I just want when I onCreate() or onResume() the activity, my app could update UI in time?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Shared Preference** for storing data...
By using this you can access data throughout your application life cycle.